# Trying to get proper JS targeting of second radio button of group change

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I want to have the `dinner[1]` input be Yes if `dinner-set[]` is checked and either of the `location_rowid_` are checked. It works for location 1 being checked but not location 2. I'm targeting with `$("input[name^='location_rowid_']",parent)` to get both inputs by starts with.
I have this js all working properly except when I select on location 2.

```js
$("input[name^='dinner-set']:checkbox,input[name^='location_rowid_']").change(function() {
  parent = $(this).closest('.table-row');
  if ($("input[name^='dinner-set']:checkbox", parent).prop('checked') == true && $("input[name^='location_rowid_']", parent).prop('checked') == true) {

    $(parent).find("input[name^='dinner']").prop("value", "Yes");
  } else {
    $(parent).find("input[name^='dinner']").prop("value", "No");
  }

  var dinner_count = $('input[name^="dinner"]:checked').length;
  var location1_count = $('.location1-count:checked').length;
  var location2_count = $('.location2-count:checked').length;
  var dinner1_offset = dinner_count - location2_count;
  var dinner2_offset = dinner_count - location1_count;

  if (location1_count > 0 && dinner_count > 0) {
    var dinner_count_location1 = dinner1_offset;
  } else {
    var dinner_count_location1 = 0;
  }

  if (location2_count > 0 && dinner_count > 0) {
    var dinner_count_location2 = dinner2_offset;
  } else {
    var dinner_count_location2 = 0;
  }

  $(".dinner-count-text").text("Dinner total = " + dinner_count);
  $(".dinner-count-text1").text("Dinner total = " + dinner_count_location1);
  $(".dinner-count-text2").text("Dinner total = " + dinner_count_location2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container food-data">
  <div class="container dinner-info1">
    <span class="text-element location-number-text">Location #1</span>
    <span class="text-element dinner-count-text1">Dinner total = 0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container dinner-info2">
    <div class="rule location-separator">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <span class="text-element location-number-text">Location #2</span>
    <span class="text-element dinner-count-text2">Dinner total = 0</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container table-row alt1">
  <div class="container table-cell" data-label="Name">
    <div class="container container-1">
      <input class="undisable" type="text" name="dinner[1]" value="No"><br>
      <label class="checkbox dinner-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="dinner-set[24]" value="Yes"><span>Dinner</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container table-cell checkin-cell ">
    <div class="container split-location">
      <label class="radio split-location-radio">
                       <input class="location1-count" type="radio" name="location_rowid_[1]" value="111">
                         <span>Location 1</span></label>
      <label class="radio split-location-radio">
                       <input class="location2-count" type="radio" name="location_rowid_[1]" value="113">
                         <span>Location 2</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/progrower/vjpux8Lw/7/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the **.prop('checked')== true** to **.is(':checked')** and it works now. Not sure why but thanks for looking.
New [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/progrower/vjpux8Lw/8/).

```
          $("input[name^='dinner-set']:checkbox,input[name^='location_rowid_']").change(function() {
           parent = $(this).closest('.table-row');
        if($("input[name^='dinner-set']:checkbox",parent).prop('checked')== true && $("input[name^='location_rowid_']",parent).is(':checked')){

                $(parent).find("input[name^='dinner']").prop("value","Yes");
                }else{
                $(parent).find("input[name^='dinner']").prop("value","No");                 
                }
               
               var dinner_count =   $('input[name^="dinner"]:checked').length;
               var location1_count = $('.location1-count:checked').length;  
               var location2_count = $('.location2-count:checked').length;
               var dinner1_offset = dinner_count - location2_count;
               var dinner2_offset = dinner_count - location1_count; 
            
              if(location1_count >0 && dinner_count>0){
                 var dinner_count_location1 = dinner1_offset;
                }else{var dinner_count_location1 = 0; 
                }
               
               if(location2_count >0&& dinner_count>0){
                   var dinner_count_location2 = dinner2_offset;
                 }else{var dinner_count_location2 = 0; 
                 } 

              $(".dinner-count-text").text("Dinner total = "+dinner_count);
              $(".dinner-count-text1").text("Dinner total = "+dinner_count_location1);
              $(".dinner-count-text2").text("Dinner total = "+dinner_count_location2);
              
      });
```